# Python Random.Choice EXCEPT One Option

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I am trying to use `random.choice()` to select an item from a dictionary, however, I would like one of the items to be ignored entirely. For example:

```
mutationMarkers = {0: "original", 1: "point_mutation", 2: "frameshift_insertion", 
                   3: "frameshift_deletion", 4: "copy_number_addition", 
                   5: "copy_number_subtraction"}

mutator = choice(list(markers)) # output is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Is it possible to use `random.choice` and ignore `{0: "original"}`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
mutator = choice([x for x in mutationMarkers if x != 0])
```

Comment: @BcK I don't think performances will be an issue for a 5 elements list...

Comment: @BcK, well, you can also define the list elsewhere and reuse it if you have to call `choice()` repeatedly.

Comment: @jpp Explicit is better than implicit :)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution using `set`:

```
mutator = choice(tuple(mutationMarkers.keys() - {0}))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `random.choices` instead and provide zero weights for those elements that you want to drop.

```
In [1]: import random

In [2]: a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

In [3]: n = len(a)

In [4]: weights = [1./(n-1) if _ != "c" else 0 for _ in a]

In [5]: random.choices(a, weights=weights, k=10)
Out[5]: ['e', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'b', 'b']
```